# smach kinetic on raspberry pi 3

Tags: ros-kinetic, smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I am using ROS kinetic on a raspberry pi 3 (with Raspbian Buster).  To install ROS on the raspberry I used this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi) and everything was running fine.

Now I want to create a program and use SMACH, but it is not installed on my raspberry. I tried to `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-smach` but its not able to locate it.
Any ideas on how to install smach on the raspberry ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/370515/smach-kinetic-on-raspberry-pi-3/) by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you check the Jenkins jobs tab on the [smach docs](http://wiki.ros.org/smach) under kinetic you'll notice a binary for buster is missing, meaning you won't find it as an apt package. Is there a reason you're still working with Kinetic? You should see the binaries exist for Noetic. I'd recommend upgrading your ROS distro, if for nothing else than in anticipation of Kinetic reaching EOL in a few months. I have smash (as a dependency of [flexbe](http://wiki.ros.org/flexbe)) working in a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container using Noetic on a RPi4. So it's possible, but you  may need to do some major changes

---

Originally posted by [chives_onion](https://answers.ros.org/users/39292/chives_onion/) with karma: 180 on 2021-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2021-01-29**:
Or, if you are set on kinetic for whatever reason, you could try building smach from [source](https://github.com/ros/executive_smach). Just create a catkin_ws/src in your home directory and clone the above repo into it. You should then be able to use `catkin build` to make smach.

**Comment by [lfvm0001](https://answers.ros.org/users/59247/lfvm0001/) on 2021-01-29**:
Thanks both for your suggestions. As is there not any particular reason to use kinetic, im gonna update the ROS distro.